# Java regex: Count words/phrases/wildcards in HTML document

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a situation where I need to find the number of occurrences of a word/phrase/wildcards in a HTML document. The best solution I thought would come out of regex. Any comments or ideas on how this can be done. If its regex can some one direct me on how I can get started on it using Java.

Comment: Regex ain't the best tool for parsing (x)HTML. [Mozilla HTML Parser](http://mozillaparser.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I don't think he really needs to parse in the normal sense, I think he just wants to count occurrences. For that, treating the HTML like a string would be fine and a regex will work well. I could be wrong though on what he needs.

Comment: Java isn’t the best tool for this.

Comment: @josh.trow I guess he wants to count/process the document the same way as we do _find_ on Firefox/Chrome or Lynx.

Comment: @josh that's correct, I would only like to know number of occurences(count) of a string

Comment: @tchrist I need that document to be parsed on different platforms including solaris,and so since java is platform independent I have no other choicee

Comment: @Sharma: That is silly.  And Java isn’t platform independent, either, especially where you need it to be. Languages that handle regexes better are perfectly portable. Perl, Ruby, and even Python all come to mind.

Comment: @tchrist- But all our code has already been in Java for more than 5 years, I cant rewrite every thing in other lang's now. Its a small part being implemented in our project. We do use perl but not for this application

Comment: I agree with sharma's last comment and his up front resistance (even though his first reason was not so good). Although Java is not the only platform independent language (by the way it is plenty platform independent), it is typically not worth it for us productive people to learn a new language just because it is more difficult to solve a certain problem in Java. @tchrist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a an example of how to count the number of matches of a regex. The example simply counts the occurrences of "foo" in the input string.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("foo");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("foo bar foo baz foo qux foo");
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Count: " + count); // count == 4
```

Comment: @haakon- Well I guess it would work. But Since I am considering HTML document, I would strip the HTML tags off before I do that. Still testing a few things

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using an HTML Parser (such as [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/)) instead of regex to do this.

Comment: is Jsoup platform independent?

Comment: @sharma yes, it is just a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Simple in Java.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("myregex");

int count = 0;

// Read each line of the HTML document into the below variable

String line = ...

if(pattern.matcher(line).matches())
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: @Haakon - What I have given is not exact code. It is pseudocode so that the asker can benefit from and write his logic rather than being spoonfed :)

Comment: `matches` is the wrong function; it doesn’t work right in Java. You need `find`.

Comment: @tchirst - it is certainly not "wrong". It does match. But find enables you to count multiple occurrences on a single line too. Where as match just gives you one match per line.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified regex I'm assuming you're just looking for key words. If you don't want to use jsoup as dogbane suggested you could always go with [Calculating Word Frequencies with Regular Expressions](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/CalculatingWordFrequencieswithRegularExpressions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Why write a zillion-line program when a command-line one-liner works perfectly well?

```
% perl -nle 'while (/pat/g) { $count++ } END { print $count }' input files go here
```

You can pretty much that same thing with many, *many* other pre-existing tools, even venerable old `awk`.  Why use assembly language when that job has already been done? Seems dangerously like NIH syndrome.

Perhaps you have other requirements that I’ve understood.  The last time a senior Java person had a question, he asked me how to tell which lines in an input file had a tab on them.  He had been going to write a Java program for this (**BOGGLE!**), but at the last minute thought there might be a better way.

There was.